# mongoose find not work as expected - null result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have started search with google and in stackoverflow.com but I can not solve this.

When I use:

```
Suppliers.find({}, function(err, supplier) {
```

get I all suppliers from the mongodb.

But when I call the following it returns: {"suppliers":[]} and not the suppliers will with smaId (for examples: 1) show.

```
Suppliers.find({ "smaId": req.params.supplierId }, function(err, supplier) {
```

Here the following complete Code with Schema to understand my problem (give not on result when I search with smaId).

```
router.get('/:supplierId', function(req, res) {
  Suppliers = conn.model('Suppliers')
  Suppliers.find({ "smaId": req.params.supplierId }, function(err, supplier) {
     if (err) {
       return res.sendStatus(500)
     }
     if (!supplier) {
       return res.sendStatus(404)
     }
    res.send({ suppliers: supplier })
  })
})
```

THE SCHEMA

```
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema

var suppliersSchema = new Schema(
  { smaId: String
  , companyName: String
  , companyNametwo: String
  , street: String
  , city: String
  , zipCode: String
  , country: String
  , telefon: String
  , telefax: String
  , emailadress: String
  , erstkontaktemail: String
  , lieferungenan: String
  , website: String
  , cat: String
},
  { collection : 'suppliers' }
```

)

Please help me. Greetings Sven.

Comment: Check your inputs to be sure that they match a document you expect. You have at least specified a full collection name so their should be no confusion there ( was not necessary since mongoose would have chosen that name anyway based on the model ), but make sure you are not overriding that in the model definition ( which takes precedence over schema ). Finally, make sure you are connecting to the right database. Some logging of input and an example document you expect to match would help your question.

Comment: Though it does not dianose the specific problem here, also note that this line: `if (!supplier) return res.sendStatus(404)` is always going to evaluate true as mongoose is going to return an array regardless of whether there is any content. So you should check the length instead: `if (!supplier.length) return res.sendStatus(404)`. But do that after you have worked out why you are not getting content.

Comment: What is example: `req.params.supplierId` and example record with that `smaId`?